# Qt 5.3 Relative path not found on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to port a game I made using Qt 5 to Mac OS. Everything is working fine, except that I have a pretty big Assets folder that I can't turn into a resource file.

On Windows and Linux I was using relative paths to load images from the Assets directory, essentially all the assets from the game are loaded via `QImage.load("../Assets/some_asset");` and the Assets folder is of course one directory up from the executable.

I have used `getcwd` to determine that the working directory for my game is `<path_to_app_bundle>/Contents/MacOS` and then I have included the Assets folder in the application bundle in the `<path_to_app_bundle>/Contents` directory, but `QImage.load` still returns false and furthermore calling `access("<path_to_app_bundle>/Contents/Assets/some_asset", F_OK)` returns -1.

I have triple checked for typos and permission issues, I have also tried to include the Assets folder in all the levels of the app bundle hierarchy, nothing worked.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.3 and Qt 5.3 with clang.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing files in resources folder in mac osx app bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165681/accessing-files-in-resources-folder-in-mac-osx-app-bundle)

Comment: OSX resources should be in the resource folder app/Contents/Resources. Qt resources are built into the executable, so if you're not using that, this answer explains how to get to the resource files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165681/accessing-files-in-resources-folder-in-mac-osx-app-bundle/24165954#24165954